# Is there a way to have multi handle sliders in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Im developing a GUI that takes a video and segment it and then display the segmentation scheme as values on a slider where the user can edit the values if they want to.

I cant seem to find a way to get a multi handle slider in tkinter. If this is not an option, what other ways I can use to serve the same purpose while being more visual than typing in the values.

This code display a scale with only one range handler, Can I add multiple range handlers to this one scale bar?

```
slider = Scale(root,orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 500, from_= 0, to = 400)
slider.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
```

Comment: Why don't you use multiple `Scale` widgets?

Comment: I need the handles to all be on the same scale. And as far as I know, having multiple scales wont solve the problem.

Comment: If you have tried using multiple scales with problem, you can post the code and state what the problem is.

Comment: I need one scale with multiple handles to record multiple values. I dont have code for it because I couldnt find a way to use one scale widget to have multiple handles.

Comment: Then why do you think that multiple scales cannot achieve what you want? What problem do you *expect to come across* when using multiple scales?

Comment: Is there a way to integrate multiple scales together to work as one scale with multiple range handlers ? The problem is that I want only one scale bar to appear with multiple range handlers on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like tkinter does not support multi slider scales or multi handles scales. There is an implementation by: https://github.com/MenxLi/tkSliderWidget/blob/master/README.md which seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I think this module [Range Slider](https://pypi.org/project/RangeSlider/) will work.

You can see how it looks,

[image: My screenshot]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31880746)

Comment: @kotatsuyaki My bad, It was just an error while copying. I have fixed the link now.